# Can't find a way to show file manager on left hand side on Xamarin Studio?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I accidentally closed the file manager (The toolbar on the left hand side that shows all the files and frameworks in the project) and do not know a way to make it show. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see there is no area on the left hand side that shows all the file hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's called the "Solution Explorer"

View --> Pads --> Solution

Comment: Oh my bad. Thanks alot sir.